# Make collection_select display as an image (Rails 3 App)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select, drop-down-menu

All,

BACKGROUND: I have a collection_select statement that displays a dropdown box.

OBJECTIVE: I'd like the dropdown to be an image that the user clicks to see the collection rather than the default box + down arrow that appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like [this plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html) for jQuery.  It allows you to replace a normal select with a custom one based on your wants.  You would have to write your own select helper since you need to add the attributes to the select options that this plugin requires.  If you get started and need help, post back here with what you're stuck on.